# mongodb pull from array without using $in

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I seem to be able to pull elements from an array of objects by an object's field without using $in and I'm not sure why. I've written two tests that prove it works but it seems crazy to me. Is this valid?

Suppose the model
`{ items: [ { name: '1', id: 1 }, { name: '2', id: 2 } ] }`

I am incredibly surprised this works without `$in: [1,2]`

`model.updateOne({_id}, { $pull: { items: {id: [1,2] } } })`

Am I getting false positives on my tests? I see the array change, etc..

Comment: What are you two queries?

Comment: If by that you mean tests, I have one test  where I pull just 1 item and I am left with 1 item, and one test where I pull two items and am left with none. I am just really not sure why this works, it should require me to use `$in`